# How to set the User Defined File Attribute in Java NIO for Unix OS?

Tags: java, file, jakarta-ee, nio, java.nio.file

I am trying to set user defined attribute to a file, for example, `version=1` to the file foo.txt. So that I can retrieve the `version` attribute later.

I see Java NIO package provide such mechanism, I followed [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html) document. However, I am trying to run this in my Unix operating system, it says null pointer exception, also I *see that the blog says*  it is window-specific. So How can write attributes to file in Unix?

```
UserDefinedFileAttributeView userDefinedFAView = Files
                .getFileAttributeView(path, UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class);
        List<String> attributeList = userDefinedFAView.list();
        System.out.println("User Defined Attribute List Size Before Adding: "
                + attributeList.size());

        // set user define attribute
        String attributeName = "version";
        String attributeValue = "1";
        userDefinedFAView.write(attributeName,
                Charset.defaultCharset().encode(attributeValue));
```

The entire source code is below: 
https://gist.github.com/ajayramesh23/e21d6159d8271fe0a4cfaf7209f6fb74

Reference blog for the source-code:
http://javapapers.com/java/file-attributes-using-java-nio/

> Please provide the best way in Java 7 or above to set the file attributes.

Also, I see that Java Doc mentioned this below note:

Note:

> In Linux, you might have to enable extended attributes for
>   user-defined attributes to work.  If you receive an
>   UnsupportedOperationException when trying to access the user-defined
>   attribute view, you need to remount the file system. The following
>   command remounts the root partition with extended attributes for the
>   ext3 file system.  If this command does not work for your flavor of
>   Linux, consult the documentation.
>
> `$ sudo mount -o remount,user_xattr /
>   If you want to make the change permanent, add an entry to /etc/fstab.`

**So How to set user-defined attributes without doing above note.**

Comment: It says "you ...have to enable extended attributes." Probably there's no way around that, short of writing your own JNI code.

Comment: Which bit of code says null pointer exception?